# Prolog: Trying to determine if a person is a citizen of a certain country

Tags: prolog

I am writing a Prolog program in which given a set of facts about the citizenship(s) of a person in the following format (meaning [name] is a citizen of a [list of countries]):

```
citizen(name, [list of countries])
```

Example: `citizen(JaneDone, [Germany, United States])`

A query is able to return if a person has citizenship in Germany. I am writing my query like this:

```
citizenOfGermany(citizenName) :-
    member(citizen, citizen(citizenName)).
```

However, it always returns an empty list no matter what value I feed into `citizenName`. This seems strange, considering that I thought that the member function checks whether the first parameter is within the second parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done a few things wrong. For starters, in Prolog, variables start with Capital letters, and you need to quote atoms that start with capital letters.

So:

```
citizen('JaneDone', ['Germany', 'United States']).
```

And in Prolog, there aren't any functions; you need to spell things out with predicates.

So:

```
citizenOfGermany(CitizenName) :-
    citizen(CitizenName, Countries),
    member('Germany', Countries).
```

And let's try it out:

```
?- citizenOfGermany(C).
C = 'JaneDone' ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

A more fundamental question is: why are you defining your facts as `citizen_of_countries/2`? Relational databases typically don't have lists, so why are you using a list for a fact? It's better to do this:

```
citizen_of_country('JaneDone', 'Germany').
citizen_of_country('JaneDone', 'United State').

citizen_of_Germany(CitizenName) :-
    citizen_of_country(CitizenName, 'Germany').
```

and, if you need a list of all citizenships:

```
citizen_of_countries(Citizen, Countries) :-
    setof(Country, citizen_of_country(Citizen, Country), Countries).
```

(I'll leave it as an exercise as to why `bagof/3` could be used instead of `setof/3` but `findall/3` shouldn't ... hint: what should `citizen_of_countries('Unknown Person', Countries)` do?)